# CakePHP 2.1 custom url for pagination links

Tags: pagination, cakephp-2.1

I am using cakephp 2.1 and I defined pagination links in 'latest' view. Its showing controller and action names in url like

`/pages/latest/page:2`.

But I want only action name in url like

`/latest/2`.

Please suggest me how to do that?.. The work will be more appreciable..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could define custom routes.

> Routing in CakePHP also encompasses the idea of reverse routing, where an array of parameters can be reversed into a string url. By using reverse routing, you can easily re-factor your applications url structure without having to update all your code.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html

e.g.

```
Router::connect(
  '/latest/:number',
  array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'view'),
  array('pass' => array('number'))
);
```